# How MapReduce work in Apache Spark and Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, mapreduce

I have this function in Scala language:

```
def generatePairs(...) = {
  val pairs = ArrayBuffer.empty[(Int, Int)]

  pairs.append((00000, 11111))
  pairs.append((11111, 00000))

  pairs
}
```

And then I use it:

```
//...
.map(t => generatePairs(...))
.flatMap(pair => pair.map(x => x -> 1))
.reduceByKey((x, y) => x + y)
//...
```

And so question is:

Is equal (00000, 11111) and (11111, 00000) in map-reduce paradigm and spark-scala notation?

Is it true in after map-reduce part end:
(00000, 11111) -> 2

OR

(00000, 11111) -> 1
(11111, 00000) -> 1

Comment: Why  (00000, 11111) would be equal to (11111, 00000)?

Comment: Maybe Spark check equal element and reduce it how an one element?

Comment: What result are you seeing?

Answer (score 0):

Assume - for example - that these are coordinates.

Are (x,y) and (y,x) the same coordinates? **Certainly not!**

Therefore, mapreduce *must not* assume that the order of a tuple is irrelevant *by default*. (That does not say it can't be done, just that the system must not assume this as default behavior)

If you want this behavior, simply output appropriate tuples:

```
if x < y:
    pairs.append( (x,y) )
else:
    pairs.append( (y,x) )
```